# Image uploading using Volley fails

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to upload image to the remote server using Volley, but Image fails to upload and there is no response from the server.

The application shows **error** as a `Toast Message`.

My MainActivity.java file

```java
package com.example.mashood.test;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;
    EditText edit1;
    EditText edit2;
    Button choose;
    Button upload;
    final int IMG_REQUEST=0;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public static String url="http://www.muftiattaullahmultani.com/android/image.php";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        edit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        choose=(Button)findViewById(R.id.choose);
        upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    uploadImage();
                }
            });

        choose.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SelectImage();
                }
            });
    }

    void SelectImage()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMG_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==IMG_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK&& data!=null)
        {
            Uri path=data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),path);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edit1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String ImageToString(Bitmap bitmap)
    {

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputstream);
        byte[] imgbyte=outputstream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgbyte,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    private void uploadImage()
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Succes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String>param=new HashMap<String, String>();
                param.put("name","img");
                param.put("image",ImageToString(bitmap));
                return param;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Server image.php file

```php
<?PHP
    include 'database.php';
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $image=$_POST['image'];
    $path="/home4/hazrat/public_html/audio/$name.jpg";
    file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
    echo "succesful";
?>
```

Application is showing error as a toast message when i click upload button. Did I miss something in the code or is there any error in server side PHP script?

Comment: Can you show what the error message is saying?

Comment: i guess `<?PHP` should be `<?php`

Comment: it is showing toast Message Inside the error listener .. Instead of execution of on response method .. error listener is being executed .. take a look at uploadImage() function

Answer (score 0):

In your `onErrorResponse` put `error.printStackTrace()` to get more info about where it errored out. I'm asuming as @pavneet_singh said change `<?PHP` to `<?php`

Comment: `com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:169)` `com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:113)`

i get this error and can not figure out problem